# Could someone explain me what does this line of code mean?

Tags: c

I was wondering what this code really means. I mean, I would like to know what it does, in what order, and what do `?` and `:` signs mean; all explained.

```
printf(" %c", ((sq & 8) && (sq += 7)) ? '\n' : pieces[board[sq] & 15]);
```

Thanks.

Comment: ternary+side effects means that the person who wrote that didn't mean well...

Comment: it will increase sq by 7 each time it is not a multiple of 8 and print linefeed, else it will just print the piece of the board (with an indirection & modulus on the index). Horrible code (and my statement about the multiple of 8 is wrong too :))

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre that's not a charitable interpretation; they might have been well meaning but wildly incompetent.

Comment: ...because of short-circuit evaluation in conditionals. When `(sq & 8)` is `false` then `(sq += 7)` does not get evaluated, because the whole expression is already known to be `false`.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre "it will increase sq by 7 each time it is not a multiple of 8 and print linefeed" --> No.  `sq & 8` is true when `sq = 8,9,10,...15, 24,25,...`, but not 0, 16,32,   It is not a "not multiple of 8" detection.

Comment: true. I didn't write an answer or use the debugger. Too complex :)à

Answer (score 3):

- The first argument, " %c", means that printf needs to print out a character.
- The second argument is the character that the function prints.
- In this case, the second argument is a [ternary operator](https://guide.freecodecamp.org/c/ternary-operator/). You can read the link provided, but in short, it's basically a short-hand for an if-else block. This is what it looks like in your example:

  ```
  ((sq & 8) && (sq += 7)) ? '\n' : pieces[board[sq] & 15]
  ```

Let's separate it into three parts:

1. `((sq & 8) && (sq += 7))`
2. `'\n'`
3. `pieces[board[sq] & 15]`

The first part is a condition (if);

- this expression `(sq & 8)` uses what is called a bitwise AND operation (read more [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bitwise-operators-in-c-cpp/)). Basically, 8 in binary is 1000 and that part checks whether sq has a 1 in that position (it can be 1000, 11000, 101000 etc.); if it does, that expression equals 8 (any number bigger than zero means true) and if it doesn't, it equals 0 (which means false).
- && means AND, it just means that both left and right expression need to be true
- `sq += 7` will add 7 to sq and if it's not 0, it is true.

The second part `\n` is returned (and in your case printed out) if the condition is true; else the third part will be printed out (`pieces[board[sq] & 15]`).

Comment: I think you should add something about [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). `(sq += 7)` will not be executed/evaluated when `(sq & 8)` is false.

Comment: More like "printf needs to print out _a space and then_ a character."

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly obfuscated code, so it's best to try to understand it in the context in which it appears.  By obfuscating it in this way, the auther is trying to tell you "you don't really need to understand the details".  So lets try to understand what this does from the 'top down' inferring the details of the context, rather than bottom up.

`printf` prints -- in this case `" %c`", which is a space and a single character.  The single character will either be (from the `?`-`:` ternary expression)

- a newline '\n'
- a `piece` from space `sq` on the `board`

which it will be depends on the condition before the `?` -- it first tests a single bit of `sq` (the `& 8` does a bitwise and with a constant with one set bit), and if that bit is set, adds 7 to `sq` and prints the newline<sup>1</sup>, while if it is not set, will print the piece.

So now we really need to know the context.  This is *probably* in a loop that starts with `sq = 0` and increments `sq` each time in the loop (ie, something like `for (int sq = 0; ...some condition...; ++sq)`).  So what it is doing is printing out the pieces on some row of the board, and when it gets to the end of the row, prints a newline and goes on to the next row.  A lot of this depends on how exactly the `board` array is organized -- it would seem to be a 1D array with a 2D board embedded in it; the first row at indexes 0..7, the second at indexes 16..23, the third at indexes 32..39 and so on<sup>2</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>technically, when the bit is set, it tests the result of adding 7, but that will be true unless `sq` was -7, which is probably impossible from the context (a loop that starts at 0 and only increments from there).</sub>

<sup>2</sup><sub>The gaps here are inferred from the test in the line of code -- those indexes with bit 3 set (for which `sq & 8` will be true) are not valid board spaces, but are instead "gaps" between the rows.  They might be used for something else, elsewhere in the code</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thank you all! I've looked at it and it now works as expected. Thanks!